# How to find a specific id withing a element

Tags: jquery

I have few divs of images created in html. The html code look like this

```
<ul class="menu controls">
                    <li class="selected"><a href="#vsetko">Všetko</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#dota">Dota 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#hunt">Hunt: Showdown</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#wow">World of Warcraft</a></li>
                </ul>
```

Let's say I want to hide the #dota id, so I tried to do it via jquery, but I cannot seem to get it work.

```
$("li").find("#dota").hide();
```

I am very new to this, could you please point me somewhere and tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This should work as described. You can also select the item with `$("#dota").hide()` or `$("li > #dota").hide()`. What is not working? If you want to hide the List Item, that would be `$("#dota").parent().hide()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologizes, ignore my comment, I had to look at the code further to see what you wanted to accomplish. Consider the following example.

```js
$(function() {
  $("li > a[href='#dota']").hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu controls">
  <li class="selected"><a href="#vsetko">Všetko</a></li>
  <li><a href="#dota">Dota 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#hunt">Hunt: Showdown</a></li>
  <li><a href="#wow">World of Warcraft</a></li>
</ul>
```

You were not trying to select an item with an ID of `dota`, instead you wanted to select a link that was referring to `#dota` as an Anchor. So you can select items with element attributes selector in this case.

```
$("li > a[href='#dota']")
```

If we break down the selector here, we have:

- `li` - Element Selector https://api.jquery.com/element-selector/
- `>` - Parent > Child selector https://api.jquery.com/child-selector/
- `a[href='#dota']` - Element Attribute Selector https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Put it all together and we can hide the one specific element.

Comment: Thank you, it works! Also thanks for the links, they were the most helpful, can't believe the answer was this simple all this time, and I had spent like an hour or so trying to figure it out.